# Bootstrap 3 vertical fluid cards in row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my template I have next structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">some content</div>
      <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4">cards with different height</div>
          ... about 15-20 cards with same width and different height
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And every row of 3 card aligned with the highest card like this:

```
*** *** ***
*** *** ***
***     ***

*** *** ***
*** *** ***
*** *** 
    ***

*** *** ***
...
```

But I need fluid vertical alignment:

```
*** *** ***
*** *** ***
***     ***
    ***
*** *** ***
*** *** ***
*** ***
        ***
*** ***
...
```

Is there bootstrap or simple custom way to do this?

Comment: I see you have the `col-lg-4` nested inside the `col-lg-9` but then the _...about 15-20_ is not in a DIV?

Comment: 15 - 20 the same elements: `<div class="col-lg-4">card content</div>`

Comment: It's just sitting in the `row` outside of a `div` though.

Comment: So, what is mistake?

Comment: I'm actually not sure what you are asking. You have a correct row (3 +9 = 12), then there is a `row` and ONE `col-lg-4` which is perfectly fine, but since it's the only one it might not display the way that you want it to. Having only ONE column in your `row` means the content will move left.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Mko4NmOSSiwy86s8sZzJ?p=preview here is example. I would like to 5 card move up near to 2 card.

Comment: like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/MN3u9n4WMkjj0p96MSDH?p=preview)?

Comment: Yes, it is, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3">some content, all right with this part</div>
     <div class="col-sm-9">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-4">
           <div class="card high">1</div>
           <div class="card high">4</div>
       </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
           <div class="card low">2</div>
           <div class="card high">5</div>
       </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
           <div class="card high">3</div>
           <div class="card low">6</div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's nothing in the `col-lg-3` and all the content is in the `col-lg-9`. Using your code the way it is posted, there would not be a fluid vertical alignment. Could you perhaps be looking for the [Masonry](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/) layout?

Comment: Yes, I looking for layout like Masonry. But can I use it with bootstrap 3?

Comment: The previous link I shared has code and a lot of information on the Masonry layout. It's very possible with Bootstrap. Remember that each row has a MAX of 12 columns. Your later code had 24 in one row so you should have started another row. BUT - to get what YOU want - simply put all the divs TOGETHER in one row (1,4, - 2,5 - 3,6).